# How to say I haven't done something

Tags: expressions

Below is exerpted from Assimil French:

> " Et maintenant, le moment que nous attendons tous : le César du meilleur metteur en scène. Cette année le prix est attribué à... Michel Bonnaud ! "
>
> Essayant de rester décontracté, l'heureux gagnant répond :
> "Merci, je suis très ému, mais aussi très surpris car je n'ai pas tourné un seul film depuis dix ans."
>
> "C'est justement pour ça que le jury vous donne cette récompense."

So here, *Je n'ai pas tourné un seul film depuis dix ans* means *I haven't made a film for ten years... until this one*, i.e. finally he made one movie.

How to say that *I haven't made a film for ten years... even now I haven't done any* ?

Comment: I’m not 100 % sure that « Je n’ai pas tourné un seul film depuis dix ans » means that he finally made a movie.

It might just as well be an attempt at humour : he’s the best director because he did nothing and the others are terrible.

If someone told me the exact same thing, I would definitely understand that he hasn't made any movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il pourrait y avoir plusieurs manières de le dire. Je propose:

> En dix ans, je n'ai toujours pas tourné un seul film.

"In ten years, I *still* haven't made a single film."