# I haven’t done something since Christmas

Tags: grammaire

From my [previous post](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30545/how-to-say-i-havent-done-something), it’s explained that

> I haven't made a film for ten years... until now I made this one.

, can be said as

> Je n'ai pas tourné un seul film depuis dix ans.

; while

> In ten years, I still haven't made a single film.

can be said as

> En dix ans, je n'ai toujours pas tourné un seul film.

Now, if one tries with *depuis* for a particular date, not a durations, how shall it be done?

For example , how to say

> I haven’t watched a movie since Christmas, until now, this one.

and

> I haven’t watched a movie since Christmas, even until right now.

?

I suppose maybe one of them shall be something like

> Je n'ai pas regardé un film depuis Noël.

But really don’t know the difference. Pls kindly suggest , thx.

Comment: As an aside: A different approach might make it easier for you to grasp the difference between your first examples: "Ça **fait** dix ans que je n'**ai** pas tourné de film" {still not} vs "Ça **faisait** dix ans que je n'**avais** pas tourné de film" {already done}.

Comment: @Alone-zee thx but would u mind explain a bit why these two forms have the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

**With depuis, depuis...que, il y a...que, voilà...que, ça/cela fait...que**:

(a) When the action is considered as still going on at the time, the French Present and Imperfect represent the English Perfect and Pluperfect respectively (French Perfect = passé composé; French Imperfect = Imparfait).

> J'habite depuis quarante ans (dans) la même maison. I have been living for 40
>   years in the same house.
>
> Il était absent depuis quelques heures. He had been absent for some hours.
>
> Depuis que je suis ici je n'ai vu personne. Since I have been here I have not seen anyone.
>
> Cela fait trois mois que je m'applique. For 3 months I have been concentrating.

(b) Where the action is already completed, the tense is the same as in English. Thus

> Depuis que nous avons débarqué nous avons été volées par tout le monde (About).
>   Since we came off the ship we have been robbed by everyone.
>
> Le temps s'était aggravé depuis la veille.. The weather had got worse since the day before.

---

When a negative is involved or implied, as in I have not seen for two years, or in it is two years since I saw him, either the Present or Perfect may be used.

> Il y a deux ans que je ne le vois plus.
>
> Voilà deux ans que je ne l'ai vu.
>
> Deux ans se sont écoulés depuis que je ne l'ai vu.

Not the omission of pas/plus with the compound tense.

---

**Your sentences:**

> Je n'ai pas fait de film depuis dix ans.
>
> Dix ans se sont écoulés depuis que je n'ai fait de films.
>
> Voilà dix ans que je ne fais pas de films.
>
> Il y a deux ans que je n'ai pas fait de films.
>
> In ten years, I still haven't made a single film.
>
> En dix ans, je n'ai toujours pas fait un seul film.
>
> Je n'ai pas regardé un film depuis Noël.

---

Reference: A French Reference Grammar (H. Ferrar).

Comment: do you actually say/write "depuis que je n'ai [...]"? I have never seen this construction with a *ne* before and it seems completely wrong to me here. Also I think "Je n'ai pas regardé un film depuis Noël." would most commonly be written as *un seul film*. It's possible to *say* it as *un film* because then you can put emphasis on *un* specifically instead of writing out the *seul*, but as a written sentence, *seul* is pretty much required.

Answer (score 1):

The use of depuis is correct, but the nuance that you want to put should be done with a change of tense, not the use of a different preposition. In the first case, "not watching a movie" is part of the past because you are currently watching a movie. Therefore you use "plus-que-parfait" instead of "passé composé" like in the second sentence.

```
I haven’t watched a movie since Christmas, until now, this one.

Je n'avais pas regardé un seul film depuis Noël.
```

and

```
I haven’t watched a movie since Christmas, even until right now.

Je n'ai pas regardé un seul film depuis Noël.
```

As a remark, my English is not very good, but I wonder if the first sentence should not be "hadn't watched" instead of "haven't watched".